# A question about expectation of $L^{p}$ norms.

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random vector, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $p\geq 1$. My question is the following. If we know that $\text{E}[\|X - x\|_{p}^{p}]\leq\text{E}[\|X - y\|_{p}^{p}]$ (provided that they exist), we can deduce that $\text{E}[\|X - x\|_{p}]\leq\text{E}[\|X - y\|_{p}]$ ?.

I try to use Jensen's inequality, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks very doubtful.

Comment: @Gribouillis For $p=1$, I can believe it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case $n=1$, and $p=2$ *(note that the statement is always trivially true for $p=1$).*

We choose $x=0$, and $y=-1$, and define $X$ as a random variables on $\{-1,1\}$ such that
$$
X = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ with probability } 1/3\\
-1 & \text{ with probability } 2/3
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $\mathbb{E}[(X-x)^2]=\mathbb{E}[|X-x|]=1$. However, one can easily compute that
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X-y)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(X+1)^2] = \frac{4}{3} > \mathbb{E}[(X-x)^2]
$$
but
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X-y|] = \mathbb{E}[|X+1|] = \frac{2}{3} < \mathbb{E}[|X-x|]
$$